# Hive static partitions issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a csv file which have 600 records, 300 for male and female each.

I have created a `Table_Temp` and fill all these records in that table. Then, I create `Table_Main` with `gender` as partition column.

For Temp_Table query is:

```
Create table if not exists Temp_Table
(id string, age int, gender string, city string, pin string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';
```

Then I write the below query:

```
Insert into Table_Main
partitioned (gender)
select a,b,c,d,gender from Table)Temp
```

**Problem**: I am getting a file in `/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/Table_Main/gender=Male/000000_0`

In this file, I am getting total 600 records. I am not sure whats happening but what I was expected is I should get 300 records in this file(only Male).

Q:1. Where am I mistaken ?

Q:2. Should I not get one more folder for all other values(which are not in static partition) ? If NOT, what will happen to those ?

Comment: Could you add your csv loading ? (you can format code with ctrl-k)

Comment: Can you provide query you used to create & load csv to your Table_Temp, did you provide how your fields were separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In static partition we need to specify a where condition while inserting data into partition table.(which I have not done).

For this we can use dynamic partition without where condition.